# Restrict API access to my Frontend app using daily random API key

Tags: api, vue.js, jwt, api-key

I'm creating an API that will be accessed solely by my Vue.js application for displaying data like movie times, video on demand links, etc. No private sensitive info, but I would like to avoid other people and bots using my resources to get free data. I know restricting an API to my own one-page frontend application is almost impossible, as someone can always either:

- Get the API key from the page source
- Spoof the referrer header to the one that my API is restricted to

So I was thinking to "attenuate the damage", i.e. the amount of bots using my API, by having the backend server generate an API key every day at noon for example. Then when the PHP loads the Vue.js application, it inserts that API key in the Vue.js code, which will use it to query my Python API. If Vue gets an "incorrect API key" error (case when the page was loaded at 11:59 and a request was sent at 12:01), the Vue.js would refresh the page to get the new key.

This way, if someone took the API key from the source, it would expire in less than 24 hours anyways. Of course someone could scrape the page to get the API key every day and still use the API, but I feel this would stop a lot of bots and spammers.

Has anyone ever tried anything like this? Does it sound like a viable solution or there is something better to be done that I couldn't find on StackOverflow?

Comment: Instead of asking about your specific solution, why don't you post the original problem you're trying solve? You want to block bots and spammers, but you need your app to be open to who? How do those people need to have access?

Comment: Front end should be calling your backed which in turn calls your api with a secured identity/key password or pref some type of token. API should be limited to only allow traffic from specified host domain. Your proposal is the equivalent to locking a door but leaving the key inside the lock. If you want simple security without much headache, auth0 offers a free developers account to get your small project going.

Comment: Thanks @TravisActon but then anyone could make requests to the backend, same as the frontend page is going to send requests to the backend

Answer (score 0):

How about Server-side Rendering from the same location (server, private DNS) as the API server?

You can write `fetch(api)` within the server function itself.